# MockMvc is not affected by spring.data.web.pageable.size-parameter parameter

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

In my spring rest API I have GET endpoint which is paged - as imput parameter i receive Pageable. By default names of parameters for paging are "page" and "size". Insteadf of "size" I wanted to use parameter with name "limit". To change this I used spring configuration parameter:

```
spring.data.web.pageable.size-parameter = limit
```

When I start my spring application, and test this manually, everything is working properly.
But when i would like to make unit tests, mockMVC always accepts parameter "size" for paging instead of "limit". I added config param into spring config of tests and normal app, but still It does not work.

```
mockMvc.perform(get(API_BASE + "/users")
            .param("page", "1")
            .param("limit", "1")
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.PRAGMATIC_API_VALUE))
            .andExpect(content().json(readFile("pragmatic/response/ok-single-user-list.json"), true));
```

Edit:
I also add my test class

```
@Test(groups = "unit")
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    //spring context - real implementation classes
    PragmaticApiControllerTestSupportConfiguration.class,

    //mocking classes
    ApiControllerMockConfiguration.class,

    //real implementation classes - business related
    DeviceApiController.class,
})
public class DeviceApiControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@Autowired
private DeviceApiCreateService deviceApiService;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void resetMocks() {
    reset(mocks());
}

private Object[] mocks() {
    return new Object[]{deviceApiService};
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    expectTenantAuthorizationCall();
    expectCreateCallContextCall();
    expectDeviceListFindCall();
    expectDeviceResourceConversionCall();

    replayMocks();

    mockMvc.perform(get(API_BASE + "/users")
            .param("page", "1")
            .param("limit", "1")
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.PRAGMATIC_API_VALUE))
            .andExpect(content().json(readFile("pragmatic/response/ok-single-user-list.json"), true));
    verifyMocks();
}
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the configuration value? Just adding it to `application.properties` ?

Comment: And without seeing how you use `MockMvc` (do you have Spring configure it or do you do it yourself or...). So please add your whole test to the question.

Comment: yes, exactly in application.properties placed in resources folder and test/resources/application.properties

Comment: I also added test class (after I removed some other tests + autowireing of some additional internal classes from my app)

Comment: You are completly bypassing the Spring Boot setup due to manually configuring the test. Instead you should be using either `@WebMvcTest` or `@SpringBootTest` and in either case autowire the `MockMvc`.

Comment: ah thank you, will try it